# How to return errors from PHP method?

Tags: php, oop, methods, return

I have a save method in my User class.

If the save method encounters validation errors it returns an array of errors that I display to the user. However this means in my code I have to write:

```
if (!$user->save()) {
   //display success to user
}
```

Surely my save method should return true on success. But how do I handle errors in that case?

Comment: Return mixed. boolean true on success, error code array otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would throw an exception in the event that `save()` runs into any problems.

If you want to provide an array of validation errors, your could subclass `Exception` and provide a mechanism for storing the validation errors.

A custom Exception subclass will also help you differentiate between exceptions your code throws explicitly (which you'd like to catch) and exceptions that you didn't expect (which should be fatal).

Here's the subclass:

```
class UserException extends Exception
{
    private $userMessages;

    public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, Exception $previous = null, array $userMessages = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        if ($userMessages === null) {
             $this->userMessages = array();
        } else {
            $this->userMessages = $userMessages;
        }
    }

    public function getUserMessages()
    {
        return $this->userMessages;
    }
}
```

Here's a silly version of a `User` class that always throws an Exception on `save()`.

```
class User
{
    public function save()
    {
        $userMessages = array(
            'Your password is wrong',
            'Your username is silly',
            'Your favorite color is ugly'
        );

        throw new UserException('User Errors', 0 , null, $userMessages);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
$user = new User();

try {
    $user->save();
} catch (UserException $e) {
    foreach ($e->getUserMessages() as $message) {
        print $message . "\n";
    }
}
```

You could also accomplish something like this by populating the Exception's $message with, say a semi-colon-delimited list of messages. You could even build a list of constants for error types, then combine them as a bitmask and use that for the Exception's $code. The advantage of these options is you would be using the built in members and not adding anything extra.

More on exceptions:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 9):

Use **try ... catch** syntax.

For example:

```
try {
    $user->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: So within my save method, if the error message array is populated, I throw an exception? How can I include the multiple error messages in the exception? So I can display them to the user.

Answer (score 3):

A (bad?) habit I picked up after playing a good bit with erlang is to return tuple values (as a php array).

```
function my_func() {
    $success = true;
    $errors = array();
    if ( something_fails() ) {
        $success = false;
        $errors[] = 'something failed..';
    }
    return array( $success, $errors );
}

list($success, $errors) = my_func();
if ( ! $success ) {
    do_somthing_with( $errors );
}
```

In my experience, this has been really handy when the wild `modify legacy code` tickets appear and you don't really dare modify anything but could more easily add more `legacy` to it.

Cheers -

Answer (score 1):

Return either true, or the error array.
And when you check for it, use this:

```php
if ($user->save()===true) {
    // display success to user
} else {
    // display error to user
}
```

the === operator performs a typesafe comparison, meaning that it not only checks if the value is true, but also if the type is a boolean. If the array is being returned it's handled as false.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to return array from validation function like this

```
$result['ACK'] = 'true';
$result['message'] = 'Success validation'];
```

on failure

```
$result['ACK'] = 'false';
$result['message'] = 'validation error message';
```

Now you can use this array in front end like this

```
if ($result['ACK']) {
    //No Error
} else {
    echo $result['message'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to, If true then success else return array of errors.

```
if ($user->save() === true) {
    //display success to user
}
```